# How to create single bundle of js files using webpack module bundler - Angular

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm newbie to angularjs, In my project Ihave so many dependencies js files which is effecting my performance of project for each file there is separate request and hence with so many files i have end up with lot of requests..I'm looking to create single bundle of these files using webpack ...I'm looking for steps to create single using webpack?

Comment: Are you using Angular or Angularjs? It's quite an important distinction. You're using both tags, but I'm not assuming you're using both frameworks simultaneously.

Comment: While posting it suggested me to add some keywords to added as came in autocomplete...my question is more specific to angular..let me know any changes to correct it

Comment: You can change tags by editing your question. Remove any tags that doesn't fit your question. The `angular` tag is only for angular version 2+, while the `angularjs` tag is used for angular version 1.X.

Comment: Thanks @NikolajDamLarsen will do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are new to webpack please go through this [webpack video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lzh8A0p3z8g).

Assuming you are using Angular 2/4/5 you can follow the below steps.

Step 1 :- install webpack by using node command.

```
npm install -g webpack
```

Step 2 :- Create "webpack.config.js" and define how you want to bundle. This file is a webpack configuration file which defines the road map of your bundling. For example in the below config i am creating three bundles. "Startup" , "SupplierModule" and "CustomerModule". These bundles will be  compiled to the "dist" directory. In case you are new to webpack go through this [webpack article](http://www.learnangularjs.net/understanding-module-bundlers-using-webpack.php)

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        CustomerModule: "./Modules/CustomerModule.js",
        SupplierModule: "./Modules/SupplierModule.js",
        Startup: [ "./node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
                    "./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js",
                    "./node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js",
                    "./Startup.js"
                   ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    }
};
```

Step 3 :- Go the folder where you have made this file and execute webpack if you want to compress the file you can use "-p" option.

```
webpack -p
```

If everything goes well you should see  something as shown below. You can see he has created three bundles as per the road map of the "webpack" config file defined in the previous step.

[image: webpack with angular]

Step 4 :- In your angular index page , remove all JS files and add reference to the files from dist folder. Please note the main angular page only need the reference to startup.js and other modules will be loaded on demand.

In case you are using lazy loading using systemJS then the below three steps are also needed.

Step 1: – Get “es6-promise-loader” and replace Systemjs

Replace systemjs with es6 promise loader. So do a NPM and get it.

Step 2 :- Install node types

```
npm install -save @types/node
```

Step 3 :- your dynamic module loader code will also change now. So the routing code becomes something as shown below

```
export const MainRoutes = [
    { path: 'Customer', loadChildren: () => require('es6-promise-
loader!../Modules/CustomerModule')('CustomerModule')},
    { path: 'Supplier', loadChildren: () => require('es6-promise-
loader!../Modules/SupplierModule')('SupplierModule') },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'Shell.html', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'Help', component: HelpComponent, outlet: "helpoutlet" }


];
```

Do webpack again to bundle the files.If you see the bundling output you can see 0.bundle.js , 1.bundlejs which is sign that your lazy loading bundling is working well.

[image: webpack with Angular]

Happy bundling...